# Appending to buffer in c++

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, type-conversion

I am trying to efficiently convert the contents of a map to a string to send via socket. I have this so far...

```
char buffer[1024];
for (iter = my_mapy.begin(); iter != my_map.end();iter++)
{
    sprintf(buffer, "%s|%ld|%d", buffer, iter->first, iter->second);
}
```

While this is working, I was wondering whether it is inefficient. Google searches for the most efficient way to convert int/long/doubles to string resulted in sprintf, which is why I am using it. But I am worried that the contents of buffer are getting copied over and over, whereas I just want to append to the end. Is this correct, and if so, is there a better way to do this? Performance and speed is #1 priority.

Thanks!

Comment: Using `%s` to copy a buffer to itself? That's *ugly* and I'm surprised it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct; the solution you proposed here will copy the buffer every time. To do better, you will have to make use of the return value of sprintf.

```
char buffer[1024];
char* end_of_buffer = buffer;
std::size_t remaining_space = sizeof(buffer);

for (auto iter = my_map.begin(); iter != my_map.end(); iter++)
{
    int written_bytes = snprintf(end_of_buffer, remaining_space, "|%ld|%d", iter->first, iter->second);

    if (written_bytes > 0) {
        end_of_buffer += written_bytes;
        remaining_space -= written_bytes;
    } else {
        perror("Something is wrong with the buffer");
    }
}
```

Notice, by the way, that I used `snprintf`, which keeps track of the buffer's remaining length. You should *always* use this instead of the unsafe version. Your application will evolve, and through great creativity *you will find a way* to overflow this buffer. Meanwhile the safety comes at zero additional cost.

(I mean no offense, of course.)

Comment: I went through the answers and tested all the different methods.

Each method was run 10,000,000 times.

My original method (along with what i have learned to be pitfalls) took: 35.96 sec

Stream method took: 30.27 sec

Andres' method took: 27.98 sec

I will use the streams right now, but I will definitely switch it to Andres' method later. 

Thanks!

Comment: "I will definitely switch later" almost never happens in the real world. Either switch now, or be sure that you're happy for your current choice to stay their indefinitely.

Comment: What @Steve314 said. Unless I'm on the critical path or I'm controlling field widths, I too prefer stringstreams. That choice could be totally legitimate.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `std::ostringstream`s, they're efficient and more C++-ish:

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream oss;
for (iter = my_mapy.begin(); iter != my_map.end();iter++)
{
    oss << iter->first << "|" << iter->second;
    //oss.str() returns the string in which everything was stored.
}
```

After that, you can still use `operator<<` to append stuff at the end of the `ostringstream`.

Comment: That was my original thought, but almost every article I read said streams were slower but safer. My buffer should never grow more than 1024, so I am not worried about that.

Comment: Do you need this code to be *that* efficient? ostringstreams might be %10~15 slower than using sprintf. I would go for this approach anyway.

Comment: *"...should never grow more than 1024..."* -- Famous last words.

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ +1. He is totally right, how do you actually know that your integers aren't large enough to overflow the 1024 bytes buffer?

Comment: @fontanini Thank you, I will use the streams for now, due to ease, but then switch to Andres' method later on.

Comment: @Steve314 no, i wasn't. He's converting a map of integers to a string. Obviously one integer is not going to overflow the buffer, but do you know how many integers is he storing? I mentioned their length, since he might be thinking "it doesn't matter, they're just 200 integers", but if each of those 200 integers have 6 chars length when converted to string(fits perfectly in 32-bit integers), then he would have an overflow. BTW he's not appending any strings, they're just integers.

Comment: @fontanini - my mistake - I was thinking that the number of items affects wherever he's copying the stuff to later, but not the buffer he sprintfs a single item to, but on second thoughts I shouldn't have made that copying-somewhere-else assumption. Basically, I read the `%s` in the `%s|%ld|%d` format string and didn't notice that it was being to keep the previous buffer state.

Answer (score 2):

You passed buffer to sprintf as both input and output. That is undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndresJaanTack: actually, the questions was "is this correct, and if so...?" So it is a correct and helpful answer.

Comment: ""actually, the questions was "is this correct, and if so...?"""
Well, if it's UB, it's not correct. You have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use stringstream instead, but if you want more efficiency then I suppose you can use straight char* for your buffer,  you will just need to make sure you grow it unless you know it won't get over 1024 bytes.

Comment: That was my original thought, but almost every article I read said streams were slower but safer. My buffer should never grow more than 1024, so I am not worried about that.

Comment: yes they aren't going to be as fast, but they shouldn't be THAT much slower and they are a lot safer.